# C# struct partially initialization

Tags: c#, struct, initialization, default-value

I have a parameters struct:

```
public struct MyParams
{
   public int    Param1;
   public int    Param2;
   public string Param3;
   public string Param4;
}
```

This is a common structure to use across application. And there are some situation in wich I need initialize only one member, all another is not used. I can Initialize struct this way:

```
MyParams testParams = default(MyParams);
testParams.Param2 = 3;
FunctionX(testParams);
```

Also I can initialize struct direct in function call, but in this case I must specify values for all members:

```
FunctionX(new MyParams{Param1=0,Param2=3,Param3=string.Empty,Param4=string.Empty});
```

My question is **Can I Initialize structure in function call line and specify only one sufficient for me member and another members will take default value**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [11.3.4 Default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I quote:

> However, since structs are value types
>   that cannot be null, the default value
>   of a struct is the value produced by
>   setting all value type fields to their
>   default value and all reference type
>   fields to null.

Comment: Wow. It seems that I have been temporary confused with struct initialization. Its really possible to call FunctionX(new MyParams{Param2=0}); and bee happy. Thank you for ansver!

Comment: So the answer would be **yes, you can**

Comment: Calling `FunctionX(new MyParams() {Param2=0});` would be identical to `FunctionX(new MyParams());`

Answer (score 2):

When initializing a `struct`, all members will be initialized to their default values:

```
MyParams p = new MyParams() { Param3 = "Test" };
```

This will leave you with:

Param1 == 0;
Param2 == 0;
Param3 == "Test";
Param4 == null;